# TFS missing original files on machine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, beyondcompare

I checked some files out for edit about a week ago and I want to check them in or revert my changes. Before I do that want to see what I've changed, but when I compare them, the local copy of the original file is no longer on my machine. How can I get the original file back without losing my changes?

Comment: Make sure you didn't switch your active workspace.

Comment: It seems the files are now back where they should be, the old turn it off and turn it on again solution seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I got pulled onto something else and came back and the problem had gone away, looks like restarting Visual Studio did the job.